# Can Buildozer requirements contain face_recognition library?

Tags: python-3.x, apk, face-recognition, dlib, buildozer

I have a python application in which I use face_recognition. 
To generate the apk file I am using buildozer.
The problem appears when I am openning the application on the phone, it stops.
I think I am having a problem with importing the libraries in the .py file or in the buildozer requirements (maybe the libraries are installed in the right path, but are installed using pip).
Another problem can be the fact that face_recognition is using dlib which is not a pure python library.

Is it possible to generate the apk having the face_recognition imported?